# what is default value for redirect_uris in google's client_secrets.json

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to extract all video comments through, using YouTube API's v3, Videoid.

> Error:  The client secrets were invalid: Missing property "redirect_uris" in a client type of default value for redirect_uris. This redirect_uris is also not present, by default, in client_secrets.json file.

kindly provide some solution.

Comment: I suspect that you have created the wrong type of credentials in Google developer console  or have not filled out the Redirect URI correctly.    You should be creating type Oauth client id type -> web application.

Comment: thank you...now it works

Answer (score 2):

redirect URIs are easy to setup. Just go to your Google Dev console, head to your oauth clientID and add the "oauth2callback" at the end of your URI origin.

For example, my my URI Origin is `http://localhost` since I like to test on my computer. My redirect URI would be `http://localhost/oauth2callback`
. Of course, make sure you're using the correct OAuth ClientID in your app.
[image]